# SerialPort Node.js stuck in 'Error'

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, temperature-sensor, node.js

I am trying to get my Arduino to send data to my computer using Node.js Serial port. Everything compiles, my Arduino is working well and sending data in the serial monitor, but the program always goes into `myPort.on('close')`, and I can't figure out why.

```
//import serial port js package
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

//opening a port
var myPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS2", {
  baudRate: 9600,
  //parser: SerialPort.parsers.raw
});

//how to pass the readline 
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const parser = new Readline();
myPort.pipe(parser);

myPort.on("open", onPortOpen);
myPort.on("data" , onData);
myPort.on("close" , onClose);
myPort.on("error" , onError);

function onPortOpen(){
    console.log("Port open");
}

function onData(data){
    console.log("data transfer completed..");
    console.log(data);
}
function onError(){
    console.log("Error. something went wrong..")
}
function onClose(){
    console.log("Port is closed. Communication terminated");
}
```

Would anyone know what are the potential reasons? I double checked my port and it really is `COM3`, therefore, `/dev/ttyS2` for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your code. I cannot say for sure they are related to
the problem you experience, but anyway:

1. The `Readline` parser's line terminator defaults to `"\n"`, whereas
   Arduino's `Serial.println()` uses `"\r\n"`. In order to get the line
   terminators match, you should invoke the `Readline` constructor with
   `{ delimiter: "\r\n" }` as an argument.
2. Piping the flow through the parser returns a new stream. You should
   watch for data events on *that* stream rather the original port.

Thus I suggest you try:

```javascript
const parser = new Readline({ delimiter: "\r\n" });
const parsedStream = myPort.pipe(parser);

myPort.on("open", onPortOpen);
parsedStream.on("data" , onData);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still same issue but appreciated nonetheless.

Comment: When I run the file, if the data is not transfered at this very moment, then node receives nothing. Could this be the issue? I would need a continuous loop listening?

Comment: @J.C: It works for me with serialport 5.0.0 / nodejs 4.2.6 / Ubuntu 16.04, a `Serial.println()` on te Arduino side, and /dev/ttyACM0 as the port name.

Comment: And just making sure: running it in your console with simple:    node yourFile.js  ?

Comment: @J.C: Actually `nodejs the_file.js`, as the executable is called “nodejs”.